# Perl redis hset not returning correct retcode?

Tags: perl, redis

http://search.cpan.org/dist/Redis/lib/Redis.pm#hset

```
$r->hset('hashname', $key => $value); ## returns true on success
```

code.pl

```
print $r->hset('h1', 'apple' => 'orange');
```

output: 0

It says it wasnt able to set the key,val but when i check redis, the entry is there..

```
./redis-cli hgetall h1
```

output:
1) apple
2) orange

so it was able to set correctly since its on redis, why is it returning 0?
Does it return 0 if key already exists but it was able to update the value?

Answer (score 0):

[hget](http://redis.io/commands/HGET) takes 2 argunemts. How is that this even works?

```
./redis-cli hget h1
```